# Does the pinata always spawn in Whimsyshire?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've played the Whimsyshire level a few times but only saw the pinata once near the exit stone.  Is the chance of it spawning random? If it does, does it always show up near the exit stone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not.

I've run 3 full clears of Whimsyshire, and never seen the pinata once.

Since the Pinata is just the Whimsyshire version of a Resplendent Chest, I would assume that it has a relatively low chance to spawn.

I would assume however, that it will always spawn somewhere near the exit stone, as most resplendent chests in dungeons do so.

Comment: You have to be careful too, since you attack the pinata to open it, you can accidentally open it with ranged attacks.  I've seen ranged characters accidentally shoot the pinata from offsceen while aiming at mobs :(

Comment: Based on the loot revived from Pinata I would say it is no where nearer a Resplendent Chest.

Comment: its not necessarily anywhere near the exit zone.  For example, I've seen runs where the pinata was right next to the entrance.

Answer (score 2):

The Pinata can spawn anywhere. On my second last run it had spawned just inside the entrance point. On my last run I didn't find one at all. I am currently at 40% for spawning but have only done 10 runs so i may have been lucky/unlucky or missed it on occasion. It doesn't seem to spawn every time however.

Answer (score -1):

I've ran through whimsyshire about 30 times on torment 1,2,& 3 and I've only seen the pinata once. In my experience, the pinata is a very rare spawn. I'm not sure what factors influence whether or not it spawns.

Comment: I disagree. This does answer the question - the pinata is not a guaranteed spawn. This answer has other problems (it is not clear, has poor grammar, and does not add much new information), but we should endeavor to be clear and helpful to new users.

Answer (score -3):

I have done 15+ runs in legendary and it has always spawned for me. As for loot I always get 4+ yellows and a bunch of gold with 5 stacks. First time I opened one I got a Horadric Hamburger which I sold for 15m.

Comment: Did you mean inferno, since I'm not aware of any 'legendary' difficulty.  Either way this isn't an answer.